# How to get css styles in code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I need to get css styles from code behind in asp.net c#, haven't found solution on the web, is it possible to get it directly from styles.css file or do I need to workaround?

I'm using themes in my web app, but I also need to do some server processing and I need colours from ccs files, which are different for each user of course:s

Comment: I just have the feeling that you are having some bad design here and that there's a better way to achieve this (whatever this is).

Comment: One of the purposes of style sheets is to provide a common place for styling/theming so any processed code shouldn't need to know the specifics about color and layout.

Comment: I think you can see the styele.css using Google Chrome(Inspect Element function). Regards

Comment: to Darin - what can you suggest then? css helps to style all the web-site, and now I just need to get colour from it to paint an image that I will send to user. Of course I can just hold all the colours in database, but I want to see if this is possible first.

Comment: mate, are you reading the question before posting ?:) I need to do that in asp.net codebehind...

Comment: Your question could be clearer so if you want to find a solution I'd look towards refining exactly what you have and exactly what you want before criticising the answers of others.

Comment: @EnderMB - it's quite clear, I want to get styles from .css file in asp.net c# from codebehind. If the question isn't clear you can always ask :P

Comment: Is this CSS file already in your solution, or are you linking to a third-party/remote stylesheet?

Comment: @dperish in the solution. Styles get updated by web designers, so nothing style based is stored in the code

Comment: If it's a user customized theme, you want to do one of a few things... Either have multiple CSS files created in advance, one pertaining to each theme, or if you want further customization then create a separate server-generated CSS response that themes only the colors you want to modify, overriding what your web designers do.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to retrieve the current styles with the following approach:

```
var targetElement = document.getElementById("myFancyElement");
var currentStyles = window.getComputedStyle(targetElement, null);
var color = currentStyles["color"];
document.getElementById("myCurrentColor").value = color;
```

The next step would be to post that `color` value back to the server. Which could either get posted as json with an XHR request, or simply set as a form value via a hidden input element, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" name="myCurrentColor" id="myCurrentColor" />
```

Comment: I need it on server side in .Net, not on client side.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, which includes an example of how to post it pack to the code-behind via a hidden input element.

Answer (score -2):

Cs file

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel1.CssClass = "RedBackground";
            Panel1.Style.Add("font-size", "200%");
/// get value back 
            string pvalue = Panel1.Attributes["class"] ;
 or 
         btn_4.Attributes.CssStyle["property"]
        }
```

Html File

```
<style type="text/css">
    .RedBackground
    {
        background-color: Red;
    }


<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
Hello
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: @Maniak7 - to get value you can use btnInput.Attributes["class"]

Comment: I need to get styles from .css file

Comment: this doesnt even come close to answering his question